# gitlab not finding protected branches option

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to make master branch to restrict. I mean no developer should be able to push into it directly, instead code should get pushed into it only after 'merge request' accepted.

So after searching in google, I found that we can do using 'protected branches' option. But unfortunately, after I logged into gitlab, I am not finding 'protected branches' option at all.

Comment: Could anyone please?

Comment: anyone anyone please?